# Compiling Sass with a rule with "content: "\\";"

Tags: sass

I'm trying to compile many Sass files using this Grunt plugin, but I'm having a problem when a file have a rule like this:

```
.my-icon {
    content: "\\";
}
```

The problem here is the use of "`\`". 
In my project the Sass file that have this code import other files using `@import` and it is imported by other files too. 
I don't know why but when the Sass has this type of rule the `@import` does not work.

Comment: interesting - I wonder if some sass compilers are treating it as a comment?

Comment: try "content: #{"\\"};"

Comment: "Doesn't work" does not describe the problem.  Does it give an error?  What is the error?  Sass seems to compile this code just fine:  http://sassmeister.com/gist/a4f4c4d42be40a01e549

Comment: If you compile a single file it works fine, but when you compile with other files using @import the import doesn't work.